# Random effect 100% correlated to covariate

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

I work on social insects. I'm measuring the effect of inbreeding in a colony versus the LD50 (lethal dose 50%) of a pathogen. So basically the LD50 is the dependent variable, and the inbreeding level (a value between 0 and 1) as the independent variable.

Now, we took a lot of individuals samples per colony. Normally I would add Colony as a random effect in my models, to account for pseudoreplication/structure in the dataset.

However, each colony has a specific inbreeding value, so colony and inbreeding level are completely correlated. Furthermore, I guess it doesn't make sense in the first place to estimate a random intercept or slope for colony, considering the fact that we only ever have one value on the x-axis for each colony, so not really a slope/intercept to speak of.

Are there other ways in which I could take into account that samples belonging to the same colony are related to each other? I guess I could make one average value of LD50 per colony/inbreeding level, but that would get rid of a lot of statistical power.

Hope the question is clear, and thank you for your time!

Comment: *LD50 is the dependent variable, and the inbreeding level (a value between 0 and 1) as the dependent variable.* They can't both be dependent. Assuming that inbreeding is an IV, then you are right that you can't fit random intercepts for colony if they are colinear, but this won't be a problem since you fit inbreeding as a fixed effect.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've edited the typo (Inbreeding is indeed the independent variable). 

I'm not sure why it's not a problem though. The general 'consensus' in my field seems to be that normally you would add colony as a random effect to account for pseudoreplication (I took many individuals per colony, and individuals in a colony are related and thus not 100% independent sampling points). 

So now that I can't add it as a random effect I'm not entirely sure what to do to account for this structure in the data.

Thanks again!